# Load data in file and enclosed caracter

Tags: file, csv, file-io, mariadb, load

I want to load a CSV file into a database.

The CSV content look like :

```
"AAAAA","DDDDD","ooooo"\r\n
"AAAAA","DDDDD","contennt exemple"\r\n
"AAAAA","DDDDD","file C:\hghjghj\gfhfhg\ssss\"\r\n
"AAAAA","DDDDD","mistake in Word"\r\n
```

I insert the content with the "Load data local infile instruction", but the last line is not included because the end of the previous field is ""\" , I don't know how i can change my code, could you help me please ?

My Code :

```vb
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Import/file.TXT' INTO TABLE 
`cree_re_import` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Thanks.
Ristof

Answer (score 1):

A `SHOW WARNINGS` after executing `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` should give you more information in case the server couldn't process the content of the file correctly.

The CSV content which you posted has incorrect format:
Backslash is the escape character within strings in SQL statements. To specify a literal backslash, you must specify two backslashes for the value to be interpreted as a single backslash:

So the 3d column in 3rd row should be
`"file C:\\hghjghj\\gfhfhg\\ssss\\"`